# How can i test windows-specific code on linux?

Tags: python, pytest, pywin32, github-actions

A core part of a package I am developing is writing to and reading from several digital signal processors. Communication with the DSPs is handled using COM objects from the PyWin32 API.

Now obviously that won't work when testing code on a Linux machine and I can't test if reading to a DSP works if there is none. However, I would like to test the remaining code around the reading/writing.

For example, I have a routine that processes some signal and writes it to a DSP and then later reads from that DSP and saves the data read. I want to test this routine without actually using the COM-object to send data to the DSP.

One way I thought about is writing a new class that mocks the expected behavior of the COM-object for every method but this would take a lot of time. Is there an easier way to test code involving OS-specific function on the "wrong" OS?

Comment: Have you considered Virtual Machines?

Comment: Could you explain further what using Virtual Machine for testing means and how this applies to github-workflows, or point me to some resources explaining the concept ?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is as much the lack of the DSP as the difference in OS.  If this is true, I don't see a VM being of much help.  If it were to be helpful, Docker might be a better alternative, but it will be no better at solving the lack of a DSP to test with.

Comment: @Steve that is correct - event if the DSP had a Linux compatible API i would have the same problem. So i basically have to simulate the DSP?

Comment: Well, if you have the source for the DSP code, maybe that would at least give you a starting point to stub everything out.  I can't imaging that your code uses that many calls.  Sounds like maybe you need to just bite the bullet.  And then I'd recommend Docker to run your test.  I'm a recent OMG Docker user.  It's amazing how much better than VMs Docker containers are.  Or Vagrant if you want to go the VM route.  I can help you with either of those if you want.  It's easy, actually.

Comment: The answer is pretty obvious. If the processing functionality is coupled with the reading / writing part, that's bad design (and they should be decoupled). Test the routine by feeding it some data that the output is known and compare the results. You could write a unit test for that, which would be platform independent.